# Mockito in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am testing a method that uses `Spring` API and I need to test it. Is there any way to test it using `Mockito`?

Method under test:

```
@Override
protected List<MonitoringWidget> handleMonitor() {
    IConcurrentMonitoringWidgetAggregator a = (IConcurrentMonitoringWidgetAggregator)AppContext.getBean( Constants.SPRING_BEAN_MONITOR_AGGREGATOR );
    return a.aggregate();
}
```

Comment: You can't mock static with mockito, if that's the question

Comment: The whole point of Spring is to use dependency injection, to be able to inject mock beans in tests. Asking a bean to the AppContext is exactly what dependency injection allows **avoiding**, because it makes the code much harder to test. Use dependency injection.

Comment: So that means I should have a context.xml for my test, if I don't use PowerMockito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inject `IConcurrentMonitoringWidgetAggregator` into the class that has this method. That way, your test case can create an instance of the class under test, passing in a mock `IConcurrentMonitoringWidgetAggregator`

Note that if `aggregate()` is fast and the result is easy to verify, it might make sense for your test to pass in a real instance of `IConcurrentMonitoringWidgetAggregator` (i.e. test the result of the call, not the interaction).